# How do I get the psuedo terminal device of the current xterm?

Tags: unix

I'd like to get the value of the current xterm window's psuedo terminal, for use in the "write" function.  For instance, when I type ps I can see that all the current processes are on pts/4.  Is there a better way to get "pts/4" other than grep on the output of "ps"?

Eyal

Answer (score 2):

The command `tty` will "Print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input."

```
write username $(tty)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use /dev/tty which is the controlling terminal for the running process. If you need to find the tty which is connected to stdin, check the sources for /usr/bin/tty.